# Azure B2C Sign up and Sign in: Create user with request using postman

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c

In the azure B2C I have so fat two user flows created

- Sign up and sign in /name: test_signup
- Sign In using resource owner password credentials (ROPC), /name: test_ropc

For the purpose of tests I manually created user in the azure ad so I can query its access token.

In order to get access token I'm using following postman request

```
POST

https://myapp.b2clogin.com/myapp.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_test_ropc/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Body

```
username:"john.doe"
password:"xxx"
grant_type:"password"
scope:"openid offline_access abcde4da-499b-4f08-a911-c1b5111c2da9"
client_id:"abcde4da-499b-4f08-a911-c1b5111c2da9"
response_type:"token"
```

Result:

```
"access_token": "...",
"token_type":"...",
"expires_in":"...",
"refresh_token":"...",
```

My question is:
how can I create user with postman request using my "sign up and sign in" user flow?
My user flow is already created all I need is the sample postman request (not able to find any out there. Maybe its just me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the policy in the list and then "Run now".

That will show you the URL you need.